# Initialization of multidimensional pointers with different dimensional anonym arrays inline

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, multidimensional-array

I am having a noob problem.
I am making tetris in c.
I want to initialize a double pointer in a struct inline for every instance.
The width of the array differs, but it is defined in another variable.
Code:

```
typedef struct {
    char height, width;
    char **shape;
} Shape;

const Shape S_shape = {2,3, (char [][3]){{0,1,1},{1,1,0}}};
const Shape Z_shape = {2,3, (char [][3]){{1,1,0},{0,1,1}}};
const Shape T_shape = {2,3, (char [][3]){{0,1,0},{1,1,1}}};
const Shape L_shape = {2,3, (char [][3]){{0,0,1},{1,1,1}}};
const Shape ML_shape = {2,3, (char [][3]){{1,0,0},{1,1,1}}};
const Shape SQ_shape = {2,2, (char [][2]){{1,1},{1,1}}};
const Shape R_shape = {1,4, (char [][4]){{1,1,1,1}}};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

It does not work. Here is the gcc error code:

```
    tetris.c:11:1: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 const Shape S_shape = {2,3, (char [][3]){{0,1,1},{1,1,0}}};
 ^
tetris.c:11:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘S_shape.shape’) [enabled by default]
tetris.c:12:1: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 const Shape Z_shape = {2,3, (char [][3]){{1,1,0},{0,1,1}}};
 ^
tetris.c:12:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘Z_shape.shape’) [enabled by default]
tetris.c:13:1: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 const Shape T_shape = {2,3, (char [][3]){{0,1,0},{1,1,1}}};
 ^
tetris.c:13:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘T_shape.shape’) [enabled by default]
tetris.c:14:1: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 const Shape L_shape = {2,3, (char [][3]){{0,0,1},{1,1,1}}};
 ^
tetris.c:14:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘L_shape.shape’) [enabled by default]
tetris.c:15:1: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 const Shape ML_shape = {2,3, (char [][3]){{1,0,0},{1,1,1}}};
 ^
tetris.c:15:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘ML_shape.shape’) [enabled by default]
tetris.c:16:1: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 const Shape SQ_shape = {2,2, (char [][2]){{1,1},{1,1}}};
 ^
tetris.c:16:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘SQ_shape.shape’) [enabled by default]
tetris.c:17:1: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 const Shape R_shape = {1,4, (char [][4]){{1,1,1,1}}};
 ^
tetris.c:17:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘R_shape.shape’) [enabled by default]
```

Gcc: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
Thanks!

**SOLVED**
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html

Comment: You'll be much better off using a fixed size array: `char shape[2][4]`

Comment: I understand that works. But I am interested to know what I did wrong.

Comment: Also it would be more elegant this way.

Comment: BTW, I cannot make that happen, because at rotation I will be cycling the array backwards.

Comment: Ok then: `char shape[4][4]`

Comment: Sure nothing is impossible but would make the code more complex for no reason. I am just setting memory and using only that memory with pointers and height/width indexes, so no need for that.

Comment: I would need to make rotatory function and boundary checks more complicated since it matters where you start reading the array.

Comment: Maybe I will post the code below, I aim at making it as short as possible

Comment: It'll be interesting to see your final result, but it's best not to post it here. If the code works, you can post it on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and ask for a review. OTOH, if you encounter difficulties while trying to implement it, you can start another question here on stack overflow. Best of luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing some `compound literals` and using the wrong type in the one you're using. Here is a small example of what you might want:

```
const Shape S_shape = {
        2, /* height */
        2, /* width */
        (char *[]) { /* Compound literals, declaring an anonymous array of `char *` with static storage duration */
                (char []) {0, 1}, /* Another compound literal, declaring a static storage duration for a `char []` that will be pointed by `char *[]` */
                (char []) {1, 1} /* Same as above, this one the next (and last) element of `char *[]` */
        }
};
```

Without the comments (for readability):

```
const Shape S_shape = {
        2,
        2,
        (char *[]) {
                (char []) {0, 1},
                (char []) {1, 1}
        }
};
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html

Comment: Aha! Thanks very much, I didn't know about this.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html

Comment: @NajibGhadri yw :)